# Can I sort list to arguments for function

Tags: python

I wanted to sort list into arguments to function

```
def funciton(*names):
    for name in names:

        print(name)

lis = ['a', 'bb', 'srg']

funciton('{}'.format(*lis) * len(lis))
```

I used formatting and in-string for but it returned genertator

Comment: If you want to pass each element of lis as a separate argument, use * to unpack the list in the function call.

function(*lis)

Comment: `funciton(*('{}'.format(el) for el in lis))` - I assume this is what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
def funciton(*names):
    for name in names:

        print(name)

lis = ['a', 'bb', 'srg']

funciton(*lis)
```